# AZURE Logic App- Outlook- Send an Email to a Distribution List

Tags: azure, email, logic, office365, azure-logic-apps

Hello I am using logic app to send some files via email  ( outlook 365) . Up to now  there was only one recipient  and the process worked fine . Recently I've had to create a distribution list  as the number of recipients is now a whole department . When I typed the dl address in the ***To:***  part , the process runs successfully but emails are not received? The DL works fine when sending from personal outlook app but not from Logic App.  Is this because Logic Apps doesn't recognise Dls  ?? Any help much appreciated .. thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Please check the DL which is being used in your logic app, as logic app is working as expected and sending emails to the given DL as per the below result**-

[image]

[image]

**Output**-

[image]

By clicking on the above plus sign, I was able to see the number of members who have received the email.

[image]